# How to call a component's method when a Signal changes in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-signals

We have a component that subscribes to a signals from a Service:

```
export class PaginationComponent {
  private readonly pageSize = this.listService.pageSize.asReadonly();

  private readonly totalCount = this.listService.totalCount.asReadonly();

  readonly pageCount = computed(() => Math.ceil(this.totalCount() / this.pageSize() || 1);

  readonly pages = signal<number[]>([]);

  constructor(
    private readonly paginationService: PaginationService,
  ) { }

  private calculatePages(): void {
    this.pages.set([]);
  }
}
```

Thew `calculatePages` pages method is used to fill `this.pages` with the pages that are shown in the pagination.

**How can I run this method, when `this.pageCount` changes?**

Comment: Maybe `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook ?? Even though it's costly. Or maybe in the computed?

Comment: @billybadass I tried `OnChanges` already but it's never executed.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you should do this -

**call signal from a component**

```
 private yourService = inject(YourService);
    localVariable: string //example
    constructor(){
     effect(()=> this.localVariable = this.yourService.yourSignal()
    }
```

**set signal**

```
    yourService class

    public yourSignal = signal<string>('' as any);
    setYourSignalMethod(yourUpdateVariable:string){
      this.yourSignal.update(()=>yourUpdateVariable);
    }
```

https://angular.io/guide/signals

Comment: I hope to achieve this without using effect, as its use is generally discouraged except in a few specific cases.

Comment: Effect is exactly how Angular expects you to use it.  It is not discouraged at all.  Nonetheless - good luck to you.

Comment: I guess *discouraged* was a bit strong. But the docs say "Effects are rarely needed in most application code […]" and they list only a few use cases. So I ended up using `computed` for now. Is there any advantage of using `computed` over `effect` or vice versa in this scenario?

Comment: The computed function is like an effect. The difference is that it returns a new (and immutable) signal of type Signal instead of an Effect, which can cause havoc and memory usage issues.  effect allows one to use change detection on the signal as well.

Answer (score 0):

As `readonly pages = signal<number[]>([])` is a signal, you can set it there if the `this.pageCount()` changes.

Something like:

```
  readonly pages = computed(() => this.pageCount());
```

Also you can do:

```
readonly pageCount = computed(() => {
const pageCount = Math.ceil(this.totalCount() / this.pageSize() || 1;
this.calculatePages();
return pageCount;
});
```

Comment: no, you can not run this.calculatedPages() in computed(). Writing to signals is not allowed in computed(). The rest of your response is correct.

Comment: You're right, hopefully they make it happen